# Reset MYSQL root password

Tags: mysql

I have windows 7 and MYsql is installed on that. I am facing now and then one big issue ... very frequently the root passwords locks and i get the below error 
SQL Error (1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Now to resolve this i use the below steps

1. Stop running Mysql service  first (Administrative tools > Services )
2. Open command prompt (cmd) and reach the directory  (using CD command) where Mysql bin  is installed (eg: C:/Program Files/Mysql/bin)
3. type mysqld.exe -u root –skip-grant-tables and press enter (don’t close this command prompt)
4. Open new command prompt and reach the same  Mysql bin directory
5. type mysql and press enter (This time, it never prompts for any passwords and you can enter mysql console)
6. type command use mysql to switch your database into mysql
7. Execute the usual command to change password for rootUPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD(‘your_new_password’) WHERE User = ‘root’;
8. Close the command prompts and go to services , start mysql. Now you can login with your new root password

but still this ===  mysqld.exe -u root –skip-grant-tables   does not respond....

Please help with the root cause and resolution

Comment: Not responding? What do you mean?
If you mean that the console is not released for all the input so it should be.

Comment: Define "now and then", after posting this on the correct website.

Comment: @Adam: Please, if you do not have enough rep to comment then the correct reaction is to wait until you have enough rep before commenting, rather than finding some completely inappropriate place to write your text instead.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to hard reset:

1. Stop Mysql service from task manager
2. Create a text file and paste the below statement

MySQL 5.7.5 and earlier:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('yournewpassword');
```

MySQL 5.7.6 and later:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'yournewpassword';
```

3. Save as mysql-init.txt and place it in 'C' drive.
4. Open command prompt and paste the following

   C:> mysqld --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt